# PHP 5.3.1 glob:// exception

Tags: php, glob

I'm having problems with the glob:// stream wrapper included in the [PHP 5.3.0](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0) version. I'm using the following PHP version:

> PHP 5.3.1-0.dotdeb.1 with
>   Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Dec  5
>   2009 20:08:29)  Copyright (c)
>   1997-2009 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend
>   Technologies

When I try to execute the following [example](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.glob.php) from the PHP.net website:

```
<?php
// Loop over all *.php files in ext/spl/examples/ directory
// and print the filename and its size
$it = new DirectoryIterator("glob://*.php");
foreach($it as $f) {
    printf("%s: %.1FK\n", $f->getFilename(), $f->getSize()/1024);
}
?>
```

> Note that I remove the folder from the original example and left only the php extension

I get a PHP error with the following message:

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for [first php file name].php

While searching at Google about this error I discover that someone had the [same problem](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43953) one year ago, but looks like they fixed it.

So... My question is: Anyone is using glob:// wrapper? Am I doing something wrong? Anyone with the same problem?

Note: I already know I can do the same in other different ways but I want to test the glob:// stream wrapper :)

Comment: Shots in the dark: Are there no more verbose errors? Can you turn error_reporting to a higher level? There should be some more info than just "stat failed". Maybe it's Suhosin blocking unusual stream wrappers?

Comment: I forgot to comment it, I disable Suhosin extension... but maybe some code patch is also applied.

If I execute it in the console I get the following output:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for /00.php' in /home/pedro/public_html/glob.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pedro/public_html/glob.php(7): SplFileInfo->getSize()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/pedro/public_html/glob.php on line 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sent this bug to PHP Bugs they confirm it's a current PHP 5.3.1 bug.

They are trying to fix it; see [Bug report #51068](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51068).

Thank you all for your answers :)

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear. It's looking for "/00.php" (note the slash) in the root directory. I guess you need getPathName here (http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.getpathname.php) not getFileName

Comment: Then it should give me all the php files in the root path and not the current folder files, isn't it?

Comment: @Pedro, it's probably checking the root path *of your server*. There wouldn't be any files there. Try `new DirectoryIterator("glob:/".dirname(__FILE__)."/*.php");`

Answer (score 0):

I discover the problem: glob:// looks like is only accepting full paths or relative paths but not current path.

For example, to retrive the current path I need to use:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator("glob:///home/pedro/public_html/*");
foreach($it as $f) {
    printf("%s: %.1FK<br />", $f->getFilename(), $f->getSize()/1024);
}
```

But I cannot use the glob://* query for get all the current folder files and folders.

However I can make subfolders search using relative paths:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator("glob://subfolder/*");
foreach($it as $f) {
    printf("%s: %.1FK<br />", $f->getFilename(), $f->getSize()/1024);
}
```

I hope this helps anyone trying to make something with this new wrapper.

Comment: Did you try `new DirectoryIterator("glob://./*");` ?

Comment: @Sekhat , thank you. that solved my problem.replacing `new GlobIterator('*.php')` with `new GlobIterator('./*.php')` works on php5.5...